# Batch file to read the contents of an xml file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have an XML file named **example.xml**. The content of it is:

```
<xml>
  <name>Wasif Hasan</name>
  <country>Bangladesh</country>
</xml>
```

Is there any way to read it using batch file like this:

```
Name: Wasif Hasan
Country: Bangladesh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your provided file content, you should be able to treat it like any normal text file using tokens and delimiters:

```bat
@(For /F "Tokens=2-3Delims=<>" %%A In ('^""%__AppDir__%find.exe" "</"^<"example.xml" 2^>NUL^"')Do @Echo(%%A: %%B)&Pause
```

*Open up a Command Prompt window and enter both `for /?` and `"%__AppDir__%find.exe" /?` to read each command's usage information.*

Answer (score 1):

Please use the appropriate tools for the task at hand. Please use a XML parser like [xmllint](http://www.xmlsoft.org/), [xmlstartlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), or [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
xidel -s input.xml -e "//xml/*/concat(upper-case(substring(name(),1,1)),substring(name(),2),': ',.)"
Name: Wasif Hasan
Country: Bangladesh
```

See also [this online xidelcgi demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cxml%3E%0A%20%20%3Cname%3EWasif%20Hasan%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%3Ccountry%3EBangladesh%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0A%3C%2Fxml%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fxml%2F*%2Fconcat(%0A%20%20upper-case(substring(name()%2C1%2C1))%2C%0A%20%20substring(name()%2C2)%2C%0A%20%20%27%3A%20%27%2C%0A%20%20.%0A)&=%27%20%27%2C&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).